# pytube program exiting after entering the link and storing it into a variable

Tags: python

When I run my code below, the program exits after entering a link.

It looks like it is actually doing something but it doesn't print out anything. It just exits in 1-2 seconds after entering the YouTube link.

The problem only occurred after I defined the functions and put my statements in it. Before that, it worked correctly.

```
import sys
import getpass
import time
from pytube import YouTube
import keyboard
from termcolor import *

osusername = getpass.getuser()

print("═══════════════════════════════════")
print("             Main Menu             ")
print("═══════════════════════════════════\n")

def Option1():
print("")
print("═══════════════════════════════════")
print("         YouTube Downloader        ")
print("═══════════════════════════════════")
link = input("Enter the link:")
yt = YouTube(link)
print("Title: ",yt.title)
print("Number of views: ",yt.views)
print("Length of video: ",yt.length,"seconds")
print("Ratings: ",yt.rating) 
print("\n")
res = input("Would you like to download this video? y/n \n") 
path = 'C:\Program Files\downl'
if res == "y":
print("Downloading video...")
yt.streams.first().download(path)
else:
print("Press any button to close the program")

def Menu():
print("[1] ~ Download YouTube Videos")


def keyPressed():
while True:
    try:
        if keyboard.is_pressed('1'):
           Option1()
    except:
        break


Menu()
keyPressed()
```

Comment: updating pytube worked! Thanks alot <3

Answer (score 1):

When I run your code. The Program stops and doesn't work for me too. Then I realised that the pytube installed in my system was an older version. So I simply updated the version of pytube by:

> pip install --upgrade pytube

After then, when I run the code the code works pretty well.